# Vertical UISlider constraints programmatically on bottom left view (Swift 4.2)

Tags: swift, constraints, uislider, swift4.2

I need to anchor my vertical slider in the bottom left corner of my view.

This is my code:

```
let slider  = UISlider()
var constraints = [NSLayoutConstraint]()

slider.transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: CGFloat(-(Double.pi/2)))
slider.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
constraints.append(slider.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.heightAnchor, multiplier: 0.3))
constraints.append(slider.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor))
NSLayoutConstraint.activate(constraints)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a leading / left constraint

```
slider.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor)
```